# How to call multiple function with @click scrolling vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

How to call a multiple

```
<tr @click="$vuetify.goTo('#detail');testclick();">
```

```
 methods: {
      testclick: function(data) {
        console.log('clicked')
      }
```

How to do it right?

Help me please

Comment: Is there any reason you can't put `this.$vuetify.goTo('#detail')` into the `testclick` handler itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a handler method which can call as multiple methods as you want:

`<tr @click="handlerMethod">`

```
 methods: {
      handlerMethod() {
        this.$vuetify.goTo('#detail');
        this.testClick()
      },

      testClick () {
        console.log('clicked')
      }
}
```